# Change head <link href=""> to another DIRECTORY by jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, regex, url, href, head

I want to change the head link href="..." for all my css files to target another directory by jquery/javascript, as the following:

It's currently like this:

```
<link href="css/style.css">
```

I want to change it to be like this:

```
<link href="../css/style.css">
```

My try is:

```
$(document).load(function () {
function headLinksChange() {
    $('head link').each(function () {
        var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace("css", "\.\.\/css");
        $(this).attr('href', newurl);
    });
}
headLinksChange();
});
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way by using the `function` overload of `attr` method of `jQuery` object. No need of regex, just string concatenation. There is no need of a function here, I suppose.

```
$('head link').attr('href', function(_, src){
    return "../" + src;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /(?=css\/)/gm;
var str = '<link href="css/style.css">\n';
var subst = '../';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```